# Why does my palindrome checker doesn't find any result?

Tags: python, palindrome

```
words = ['Anna', 'Alexey', 'Alla', 'Kazak', 'Dom']

def palindrome():
    filtered_2 = list(filter(lambda x: x == x[::-1], words))
    print(filtered_2)

palindrome()
```

The code should return palindrome words, but it gives me an output like this:

```
[]
```

It should give:

```
['Anna', 'Alla', 'Kazak']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to normalize the input before comparisons. Basically you are checking if `'A' == 'a'` which will fail.

Try this example where I normalize to lowercase using `str.lower()`:

```
words = ['Anna', 'alexey', 'Alla', 'kazak', 'dom']

def palindrome():
    filtered_2 = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() == x.lower()[::-1], words))
    print(filtered_2)

palindrome()
```

Comment: Would be a bit cleaner to `map(str.lower, words)` instead of lowering twice each word (although this will make the results appear lower and not match the original list...)

Answer (score 3):

If using Python >= 3.8, it is possible to use [the walrus operator (`:=`)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to keep the original words in the result and have only one `.lower()` call per word:

```py
    filtered_2 = [x for x in words if (y := x.lower()) == y[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me also highlight the fact that the definition of the function `palindrome` as in your code is pointless and the script would work exactly the same without defining the function:

```
words = ['Anna', 'alexey', 'Alla', 'kazak', 'dom']
_words=map(str.lower,words)
filtered_2 = list(filter(lambda x: x == x[::-1], _words))
print(filtered_2)
```

But if you want to make it with a function this is the simples way:

```
def palindrome(words_list):
   _words=map(str.lower,words)
   filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() == x.lower()[::-1], words))
   return filtered
```

In this way this code

```
words = ['Anna', 'Alexey', 'Alla', 'Kazak', 'Dom']
palindrome(words)
```

would return the results you want.